# How can I force break word in same length?

Tags: html, css, word-break

I have text like (without any space)

```
"abcdefgh",
```

I want to use html & css to change the style to make it looks like:

```
ab cd ef gh
```

Is there any way to do this with only html & css?

The text is always like "abcdefgh", cannot use JavaScript or manually to split it.

Thanks for your help.

Like in css there is a property called

```
work-spacing
```

but with this property there must have 'space' in my string. Which is not a good solution for me. Is there any property in css so that I can break my string in a certain length?

Like break length equal to 2 then my string became  "ab cd ef gh".

Comment: what do you mean by, text is always like `abcdefgh`

Comment: @NoDownvotesPlz I mean it's a string without any space.

Comment: "cannot use javascript to split it" Don't want to?

Comment: I would be great if you show some of your codes.

Comment: @Jonathan Yes. Use only html css.

Comment: @user1441816 Just update the question.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap
word-wrap:break-word 
I think it's not precisely what you want but, maybe it is, so I share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something look like that:

```
<div>abcdefgh</div>

<style>
    div {
        width: 40px;
        letter-spacing:10;
        word-break: break-all;
    }
</style>
```

The result:
a  b
c  d
e  f
g  h

Comment: I've changed that example.

Comment: am I wrong or is this going to space ever letter where he wants it grouped in 2?

Comment: No, you are right. Put that code in this site (http://htmledit.squarefree.com/) to show the result:

Comment: ok thought so... without just reason for not using javascript I don't see the point of this question...

Comment: The question is "How can I force break word in same length?" thus I tried that.